# Who holds the license for Cadillacs & Dinosaurs?

Tags: intellectual-property, cadillacs-and-dinosaurs

> **Science Fiction and Fantasy:** [Who holds the license for Cadillacs & Dinosaurs?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5286/who-holds-the-license-for-cadillacs-dinosaurs)

Who currently owns the *[Cadillacs & Dinosaurs/Xenozoic Tales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenozoic_Tales)* license? (Or, how can I find out who does?)

Comment: Current license ownership is generally thorny, muddy, and not public unless the subject of a recent hyperbolic media release. Your best bet is to contact someone central to the original game's licensing negotiations and asking them, such as Mr Mark Schultz. (My best guess is the game license likely reverted to the owner of the *Xenozoic* copyright after a number of years, whoever that is, likely Mr Schultz still.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie has the jist of it, most likely, though another source to check (that might be more available for questions) would be Denis Kitchen of Kitchen Sink Press, the publisher of Xenozoic Tales.  Kitchen Sink Press is out of business, but Denis Kitchen maintains a [web presence](http://www.deniskitchen.com/).

Comment: -1 Crossposting is the debil - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5286/who-holds-the-license-for-cadillacs-dinosaurs

Comment: Closed due to already answered cross post.